# The electron: "portion" or "torsion" in "Fiat Homo"?

Tags: translation, a-canticle-for-leibowitz

I read *A Canticle for Leibowitz* decades ago, in French translation. It left a durable impression on me.

To my shame I admit I never reread it in English when I became able to. So I still do not know if there was or was not a translation error (or maybe just a typo) when Brother Francis discussed the "electron" with some other monk. Of course, at that time, they had absolutely no idea what it was all about. It was in "*Fiat Homo*", not in "*Fiat Lux*".

The definition of the electron they had read somewhere was, in French "torsion du néant négativement chargée". But what is the English original? "Torsion" seems weird to me. Was it originally "portion of void"? (Or another word for "néant", of course; I am just trying to translate back. Maybe "nothingness", "emptiness"?)

---

After this question was answered, I asked a second one in the comments, about a footnote that existed in the edition I had read. But all the answers were that no such footnote existed in the English versions, nor in two different French versions (one that I had found myself).

But it finally occurred to me where I had read *Fiat Homo*. I was in a book in French, *Le Matin Des Magiciens* by Louis Pauwels and Jacques Bergier.

So the footnote is neither by the author  W. M. Miller, nor by a translator, but obviously  by  Louis Pauwels and/or Jacques Bergier.

So I looked for the book on the Web (I lost my old copy in one or another moving) and actually found it.

Here is the footnote :

Définition exacte (donnée par le Pr Léon Brillouin, puis reprise par Robert Andrews Mullikan, prix Nobel). Elle est en effet incompréhensible si l’on n’a pas le contexte, c’est à dire toute la complexe structure de notre physique.

I copied it exactly **as it appears**, including the typo in the name of Millikan.
Note that Millikan measured the charge of the electron in 1909, long before the notion of spin was proposed in 1925. Granted, Kelvin vortex theory had already been abandoned by that time. But I am not sure than Brillouin and Millikan thought about the spin.

Moreover J. J. Thomson (**not** William Thomson, later Lord Kelvin) who later got the Nobel Prize in 1906 for having discovered the electron in 1897, had earlier worked on Kelvin’s vortex theory. How much of his earlier interest might have influenced Brillouin and Millikan is unclear.

---

Second Edit

I did not find a source for either Brillouin nor Millikan.

But I did find two sources for Larmor, who in the last years of the 19th Century was still working within the framework of Kelvin "Vortex Model" (yes, Clara Diaz Sanchez, you were right !!!). That was decades before the notion of spin has appeared.

See more details in [another part](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14026/is-there-a-source-for-a-footnote-in-a-canticle-for-leibowitz-about-the-definit/14030#14030) of StackExchange.

Comment: It's weird, but I think it would be pretty decent poetic description of electron, with it's negative charge, spin and being a separate entity in spacetime. A twisted and negatively charge bit of otherwise empty spacetime.

Comment: @Mithoron I see that you share with Buzz (not here, but in his comment on Clara Diaz Sanchez's answer below) the idea that this "twist" is related to the  spin. But see the comments below. Clara Diaz Sanchez opinion that "twist" is an allusion to Kelvin's vortex theory (abandoned more than one century ago) seems to me much more probable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my (English) copy the electron is defined as "a Negative Twist of Nothingness", which is very close to the French translation. The monks then banter a little bit, asking how could you negate a nothingness — "Wouldn't that make it a somethingness?".

Comment: So it was indeed "torsion", no translation error nor typo. Thanks !

Comment: IRRC, there is a footnote giving a "real world" source for this definition. Is it in your english copy ?

Comment: @Alfred, No, there's no footnote in my copy. It does sound like Kelvin's vortex theory though.

Comment: Kudos ! You know more than I do about (abandoned) physical theories, and I am (supposed to be) a theoretical physicist....

Comment: @Alfred The "twist" is probably a reference to the intrinsic spin of the electron.

Comment: The conversation between Francis and Jeris appears quoted online in two different versions—apparently the difference between the magazine ( https://books.google.com/books?id=ABOdi6e5OiUC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61 ) and novel versions.  The "Negative Twist of Nothingness" is in both versions, however.

Comment: @Buzz Can one actually see the text from your link? I don't see how. Re your previous post, the "twist" is probably not what we now know as the spin? Rather, see Clara Diaz Sanchez comment above. Most probably an allusion to Kelvin's vortex theory. In one of the versions you mention, is there by any chance a footnote ? There was one in the french translation giving a reference to a physicist  of our "real world" but I don't remember to whom. But quite possibly Kelvin...

Comment: @Alfred The Google books link works when I am logged into GMail.  However, there is no footnote in any version that I ever recall seeing.  I still think that spin is much more likely that Kelvin's vortex model, based on 1950s thinking about physics and electronics.  However, Clara Diaz Sanchez is apparently also a physicist, so I respect her differing opinion.

Comment: No footnote in my 1972 paperback. I can see the text in Buzz's link.

Comment: Connecting the phrase to Kelvin's theory is just an idea of mine - I don't have any evidence for it. Kelvin's theory applied to atoms after all, not electrons. It would be nice to see that footnote, but I've looked at the 1961 translation by Claude Saunier and not found it though.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I know it is just an idea of yours, but I like it ! Re:  translation, I found two french translations. The one by Claude Saunier does not match my memory. It says about what to do with the "electron"  "Le mettrions nous sur l'autel, dans la chapelle?". A different one says "Sur le maître-autel, peut-être?". which is what I remember. Alas the edition I found it in also does not have a footnote and it says at the end "traducteur inconnu" https://fr1lib.org/book/12114339/5a64bc

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez  The reason I prefer Kelvin's theory to spin is the word "torsion" used by the translator who added the footnote. "Spin" evokes a rotation, something dynamical. A priori "Twist' might **also** evoke rotation. But "torsion" as a **choice in french** for "twist" evokes something static. Not something that "spins", that keeps "twisting", some part of "nothingness" that has been "twisted" once and for all, "tordue". So this is what the **translator** had in mind. What **Miller** had in mind is still another question ;)

Comment: @Buzz  See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14026/is-there-a-source-for-a-footnote-in-a-canticle-for-leibowitz-about-the-definit and my own provisional (not accepted !) answer to my own question. I don't believe that "twist" refers to the spin. Larmor, in the last years of the 19th Century, used the word "twist" to describe the electron within Kelvin's "Vortex Theory", decades before the notion of spin emerged.